# Issues with permission_handler

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying out the exact example shown [here](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-example-tab-).

Tried with Android emulator first. App showed up and the snackbar correctly appeared on "Info" click. But nothing happens when I tap on the ListTile. Here's the console log

Debub console logs upon starting the app:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...<br>
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.<br>
D/FlutterActivity(26530): Using the launch theme as normal theme.<br>
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(26530): Setting up FlutterEngine.<br>
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(26530): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.<br>
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(26530): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.<br>
D/FlutterView(26530): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@bc54d44<br>
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(26530): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /<br>
D/EGL_emulation(26530): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0068900: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe010aaf0)<br>
D/eglCodecCommon(26530): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 0<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 1<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 2<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 3<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 4<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 5<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 7<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 8<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 11<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 12<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 13<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 14<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 15<br>
```

Console logs on tapping any ListTile:

```
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 0<br>
I/flutter (26530): PermissionStatus.undetermined<br>
I/flutter (26530): PermissionStatus.undetermined<br>
D/permissions_handler(26530): No permissions found in manifest for: 1<br>
I/flutter (26530): PermissionStatus.undetermined<br>
I/flutter (26530): PermissionStatus.undetermined<br>
```

Next, I tried with iPhone simulator. Things got even weirder there. Got below console logs on startup.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...<br>
Xcode build done.                                           23.6s<br>
```

Again, snackbar worked fine. Upon tapping the ListTile, the application just got closed, with just below logs in console.

```
Lost connection to device.<br>
Exited (sigterm)<br>
```

Any idea what's happening?

Permission Handler version used - permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.3
Flutter version - 1.12.13+hotfix.9
Dart version - Dart 2.7.2

Flutter clean is all green. And tried "flutter clean" too - no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add permission on both AndroidManifest.xml for android and Info.plist for IOS

For android:
android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

For IOS:
ios\Runner\info.plist

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application needs to access your microphone</string>
```

Add necessary permission in both files and re-run it should be fine.